# Cannot open libreoffice

Tags: libreoffice

All of a sudden I cannot open any LibreOffice applications.

I have created a number of word documents and spreadsheets and kept them on my desktop.

But I can neither open any of them now nor create any new spreadsheets or word documents.

Comment: Hi Carol, could you please try opening a terminal window (Alt-Ctrl-T) and run the command `lowriter` ? This will attempt to open LibreOffice Writer, and if it fails, there should be error messages displayed in the terminal window. If you could let us know what those error messages say, that would be helpful to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Simply stating that something is not working is not helpful for support. Please provide additional information as requested above as well as version of Ubuntu and libreofice. See also http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html

Comment: Hi Carol, 9 out of ten times, if applications suddenly stop working without an obvious cause, local settings are corrupted. Remove (or rename) `~/.config/libreoffice`, log out and back in.  `~/.config` is a (by default) hidden directory in  your home folder. Press Ctrl+H to make it visible. Note that possible settings will be lost.